# Extraction of a name from a string with variable number of separators

Tags: regex, r

I would like to extract part of a foldername which as the form `123456_Letters_CAPITAL_name_extension`.

The name can be `LETTERS123`, `LETTERS_123_LETTERS` or `LETTERS_LETTERS_123`.

Currently, I'm extracting the name with `unlist(strsplit(foldername , sep="_"))[4,length(unlist(strsplit(foldername , sep="_")))-1]`

**But I would like to be able to extract it if the `_CAPITAL` part is not present** (it would be 3 instead of 4 but I would like to have a general way of doing it).

`130615_Screen_II_SN_KB_3_lxb/`, `130615_Screen_II_AL343_lxb/`, `130615_Screen_II_HK_344_LM_lxb/` are representative examples of complete foldername

I tried but could not figure any regex that would do that. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Is it really `_extension` and not `.extension`?

Comment: Yes, it is a folder name.

Comment: I don't undertand how you `split` function works. Where are the variables? Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: Do you mean `strsplit`? For example, if the string is stored as a variable called `txt`, then you get the components via `strsplit(txt,"_")[[1]]`.

Comment: probably is, but what's that `length` thing there? we need some reproducible example of whats the input and whats the desirable output

Comment: My bad, it is strsplit, I edited to make it more understandable

Comment: @Math So you are saying e.g in `130615_Screen_II_SN_KB_3_lxb/`  `II` is `_CAPITAL` part

Comment: @ChinmayPatil : Exactly, its stands for 2 in roman numeration and could be higher for other screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one:

```
^\d+_[a-zA-Z]+_(?:[A-Z]+_)?([A-Z]+\w+)_[^_]+$
```

The name will be in group 1.

A perl way to test it:

```
my $re = qr~^\d+_[a-zA-Z]+_(?:[A-Z]+_)?([A-Z]+\w+)_[^_]+$~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say $1 if /$re/;
}
__DATA__
130615_Screen_II_SN_KB_3_lxb/
130615_Screen_II_AL343_lxb/
130615_Screen_II_HK_344_LM_lxb/
130615_Screen_HK_344_LM_lxb/
```

**output:**

```
SN_KB_3
AL343
HK_344_LM
HK_344_LM
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

^\d+_[a-zA-Z]+_(?:[A-Z]+_)?([A-Z]+\w+)_[^_]+$

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question as OP says `[A-Z]+` part in your regex should be optional and `(\w+)` part doesn't satisfy condition by OP that `name` may contain underscores.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil: Yes, you're right, except the interpretation of `\w`. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect, this solution works. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: This still doesn't take care of case `'130614_Screen_LX_T5_lxb/'`

Comment: It does, since \w matches numbers as well. I used the option perl=TRUE, I don't know about the exact match for R regex syntax but it's fine with this option

Answer (score 1):

Let's tackle the problem step by step. 
x below covers all possible cases as mentioned in question. (OP please confirm)

```
x <- c("123456_Letters_CAPITAL_LETTERS123_extension/", "123456_Letters_CAPITAL_LETTERS_123_LETTERS_extension/", "123456_Letters_CAPITAL_LETTERS_LETTERS_123_extension/", 
    "123456_Letters_LETTERS123_extension/", "123456_Letters_LETTERS_123_LETTERS_extension/", "123456_Letters_LETTERS_LETTERS_123_extension/")
# Lets strip out the parts which we can first..
y <- gsub("[0-9]+_[A-Z]+[a-z]*_(.*)_[a-z]+/", "\\1", x)
y
## [1] "CAPITAL_LETTERS123"          "CAPITAL_LETTERS_123_LETTERS" "CAPITAL_LETTERS_LETTERS_123" "LETTERS123"                 
## [5] "LETTERS_123_LETTERS"         "LETTERS_LETTERS_123" 


#Now we can see that if you have 3 or 1 underscore 
#you need to strip out first part


ifelse(sapply(gregexpr("_", y), FUN = function(X) length(X[X != -1])) %in% c(1, 3), gsub("[A-Z]+_(.*)", "\\1", y), y)
## [1] "LETTERS123"          "LETTERS_123_LETTERS" "LETTERS_LETTERS_123" "LETTERS123"          "LETTERS_123_LETTERS"
## [6] "LETTERS_LETTERS_123"
```

Comment: That's the problem, name contains _ and that's why I couldn't find any suitable expression

Comment: I think you should give some sample examples. Difficult to guess what you are talking about.

Comment: name = `LETTERS_123_LETTERS` or name = `LETTERS_LETTERS_123`, thanks for your help.

Comment: we need whole folder name... not just "name" part.

Comment: `130615_Screen_II_SN_KB_3_lxb/`, `130615_Screen_II_AL343_lxb/`, `130615_Screen_II_HK_344_LM_lxb/` are representative examples.

Comment: Always add more info to your original question and not commentary so that other SO users can see all info at one place

Comment: Almost, I checked and I also have 130614_Screen_II_LX_T5_lxb which is not corrected by your method. I took M42 solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Math that use case was not stated in your question

Comment: @Math : Other solution still doesn't take care of all the use cases then